# How can I run Ansible with root user and then change to another?

Tags: ansible

I have my fresh Ubuntu server on Linode and I have a root password for that server.

Now my Ansible playbook is like this:

```
- hosts: linode
  sudo: true
  remote_user: user1
  roles:
     - role: common
     - role: apache2
```

I want to execute the playbook as `user1`, but thing is `user1` does not exist yet and I don't want to run roles as `root`.
I need to manually create `user1` before running a playbook.
Is there any way to automate that?

Comment: OT: should be directed to ServerFault (or Unix&Linux, SuperUser, but even that would be a stretch)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep in mind that you are allowed multiple "plays" in a single playbook file. 
So this could be the contents of a single playbook file:

```
- name: First play, to create the user
  hosts: linode
  sudo: true
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
    -  name: create my user
       user: name=user1 password=etc... 

- Second play, to do the rest of the work
  hosts: linode
  sudo: false
  remote_user: user1
  roles:
     - role: common
     - role: apache2
```

Note that I have used a task to create the user, but that could be a role so you can re-use it between different projects.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a very simple *bootstrap* playbook that you run as root and it'll create your `user1` which will then run all the other playbooks.